# Eclipse complains for the readonly .classpath file

Tags: eclipse, classpath

We keep .classpath files in ClearCase. When a teammate gets a project from ClearCase, Eclipse complains that .classpath file is readonly. It is readonly because the teammate has not checked it out. We don't want them to check-out .classpath files, as changes on these files should be reflected to their workspaces without extra effort.

Is there anything we can do to stop Eclipse complain about readonly .classpath files?

Comment: What are you doing when it complains?

Comment: I checkout the file. But some of other users are non-programmers, we want them to be able to use eclipse without checking out this file.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the JDT source code it is expected that this file is available and is read/write at all times. I don't see anything to work around this.

Comment: Why is that? I should check it out only if I want to change it.

Comment: I can't answer for JDT design decisions. I don't see any evidence in the code that this has ever been considered as a requirement.